# Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled, but loader is already installed

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, webpack, error-handling

This is the full error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
```

but topLevelAwait is already enabled in webpack.config.js.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // The entry point file described above
  entry: './src/index.js',
  // The location of the build folder described above
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{ 
        test: '/\.js|\.jsx$/', 
        use: 'raw-loader' }],
  },
  // Optional and for development only. This provides the ability to
  // map the built code back to the original source format when debugging.
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
  },
};
```

js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDLl4mlsDgKXzYqu7BtWj60Gne3ybwxEXU",
  authDomain: "tutorbuddy-a5411.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "tutorbuddy-a5411",
  storageBucket: "tutorbuddy-a5411.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "402150617426",
  appId: "1:402150617426:web:eaab24a4375b5c543cca8b",
  measurementId: "G-B2KF86YVXC"
});

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const todosCol = collection(db, 'todos');
const snapshot = await getDocs(todosCol);
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Probably a really simple answer, but I've been at this for a while haha any help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message when trying to addoc, it had already created the webpack config file and it kept failing. I solved it by just wrapping with an async function as follows:

[image: image of code]

Comment: Please post code with proper formatting, not images of code